# how to php preg_match_all find exact words

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

i am trying to get exact word **`846002`** from html code by using `preg_match_all`

**php code :**

```
<?php
    $sText =file_get_contents('test.html', true);
    preg_match_all('@download.php/.[^\s.,"\']+@i', $sText, $aMatches);
    print_r($aMatches[0][0]);
?>
```

**test.html**

```
    <tr>
        <td class=ac>
            <a href="/download.php/846002/Dark.zip"><img src="/dl3.png" alt="Download" title="Download"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**output:**

```
download.php/829685/Dark
```

but i want to output only,

```
829685
```

Comment: if you are trying to get all the folder names which are always between `/download.php/` and `filename.zip` it's better if you just explode the string and get the third array value... much easier. Anyway that href looks pretty weird, doesn't seem a path, either a friendly url xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the slash in the character class and capture in group 1:

```
preg_match_all('@download.php/([^\s.,"\'/]+)@i', $sText, $aMatches);
```

The value you're looking after is in `$aMatches[1][0]`

Comment: hi i have test this output get download.php/829685

Comment: @user3214453: The value you want is in `$aMatches[1][0]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a group by ( and )

```
preg_match_all ( '@download.php/([^/]+)@i', $sText, $aMatches );

print_r ( $aMatches[1][0] );
```